# how to open a view by CJuiDialog in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, zii-widgets

I want to open a view by calling its action in the CJuiDialog, here is my code :

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
   'id' => 'Exe1',
   'options' => array(
     'title' => 'URL + Key',
     'autoOpen' => false,
     'width' => 500,
     'height' => 300,
     'close'=>"js:function(){
            $('#mydialog').removeData('emailid');
        }",
   ),
));

// GETTING THE ID
echo "the view";

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
```

so how I can pass a url for an action in this widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply open an **iframe** in that place and open your view(I mean **url**) with a layout that doesn't have header nor footer .